# Xamarin iOS Development - Provisioning

Tags: ios, xamarin

Do I need to have an actual physical iPhone or iPad to develop iOS apps with Xamarin?
I am getting an error about there being not provisioning profiles detected.

I know I have to provision a profile to a device. I was wondering is it possible to create a virtual device and provision a profile to that?
I haven't been able to find in the documentation where to do that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You dont need an actual device to develop for iOS, but it helps a lot.

You can use the iPhone/iPad Simulator but only on a Mac. You also have to install XCode for this. But like you said, you need to create a Provisioning Profile online on developer.apple.com with App IDs or use a WildCard. I suggesst reading something like
[this](http://mobiforge.com/design-development/deploying-iphone-apps-real-devices)

Comment: Just want to clarify something... You don't need Provisioning Profile to run application on iPhone/iPad Simulator.

Answer (score 0):

- Yes, you need a provisioning profile for deploying & testing your
  apps on a real iPhone, iPod or iPad.
- You need XCode, no provisioning profile or such, for an iPhone or iPad simulator. Note: this is not an emulator, it "mimics" only the software on the phone, not the hardware. Like this it's possible that your app may run way different than a real phone or tablet.
- Their is another way to deploy & test your app: [Testflight](http://developer.xamarin.com/guides/ios/deployment,_testing,_and_metrics/testflight_deployment/). Xamarin Studio supports Testflight directly form the IDE. You should give that a look.